# Optimize the inline query

Tags: sql, db2

Is it possible to optimize the following SQL query?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT msi.segment1,
         msi.segment2,
         mmt.inventory_item_id,
         count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY msi.segment1,msi.segment2,mmt.inventory_item_id) AS shipped_count
  FROM mtl_material_transactions mmt,
       mtl_system_items msi
  WHERE mmt.inventory_item_id = msi.inventory_item_id
    AND mmt.inventory_item_id IN (SELECT inventory_item_id ROM mtl_system_items WHERE segment2 = '92155')
    AND mmt.transaction_type_id = '63'
    AND trunc(mmt.creation_date) BETWEEN '1-APR-2015' AND '30-APR-2015'
)
```

Comment: Yes it can be dont use in in where clause use join. May be its helps you. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the execution plan and go from there.

Comment: this query ran for almost 5 hr without any output.Can some1 provide me the updated query?

Comment: Show us the execution plan

Comment: This is a strange query. You want each segment1-segment2-inventory_item_id combination to appear as often as its count? This is at least what the query does. Is this really desired?

Comment: And the outer query (`select * from (...)` is superfluous of course. Or have you truncated the query by mistake or on purpose? Maybe you'd like to tell us, what this query is supposed to do.

Comment: BTW: You should use standard SQL date literals, rather than relying on a matching language setting to recognize your month names. E.g. `date('2015-04-01')`. And you should use explicit joins `FROM mtl_material_transactions mmt JOIN mtl_system_items msi ON mmt.inventory_item_id = msi.inventory_item_id). That comma join syntax you are using was outdated in the beginning of the 1990s

Comment: And tell us about your tables: Is `inventory_item_id` unique in one of the tables involved?

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem I suspect will be your nested select statements. If you split these into simple inner joins, you should see more timely results...

```
    select msi.segment1, msi.segment2, mmt.inventory_item_id, count(*) over (partition by msi.segment1, msi.segment2, mmt.inventory_item_id) as SHIPPED_COUNT
    from mtl_material_transactions mmt
    inner join mtl_system_items msi on msi.inventory_item_id = mmt.inventory_item_id
    where msi.segment2 = '92155'
       and mmt.transaction_type_id = '63'
       and year(mmt.creation_date) = 2015 and month(mmt.creation_date) = 4
    group by msi.segment1, msi.segment2, mmt.inventory_item_id
```

I'm thinking you will need a GROUP BY clause as you have used the aggregate function count(*) along with column values in your select.

Hope this helps!